# getting ratio by iterating over two columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hi my data frame is as below

```
Date       Key  y
1/2/2013    A   1
1/2/2013    B   2
1/2/2013    C   1
2/2/2013    A   1
2/2/2013    c   1
2/2/2013    B   3
```

I now want to create a new column "ratio" which is for a given date(1/2/2013), ratio of key A would be y(A)/(y(A)+y(B)+y(C)) which is 1/(1+2+1) i.e 0.25. My final df would be as follows

```
Date       Key  y   ratio
1/2/2013    A   1     0.25
1/2/2013    B   2     0.5
1/2/2013    C   1     0.25
2/2/2013    A   1     0.2
2/2/2013    c   1     0.2
2/2/2013    B   3     0.6
```

really appreciate the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `groupby().transform('sum')` to compute the sum of the group, then it's just a simple division:

```
df['ratio'] = df['y']/df.groupby('Date')['y'].transform('sum')
```

Output:

```
       Date Key  y  ratio
0  1/2/2013   A  1   0.25
1  1/2/2013   B  2   0.50
2  1/2/2013   C  1   0.25
3  2/2/2013   A  1   0.20
4  2/2/2013   c  1   0.20
5  2/2/2013   B  3   0.60
```